# Add adsense banner next to my logo in header (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, adsense

I have a logo in the header of my wordpress site and I would like to add an adsense banner next to it like this : [image: adsense banner header]

For my logo, I have a div logo and this css code :

```
#logo { float: left; margin-top: 60px; }
```

I know I need to create a new div for my adsense code but what css code should I use so the adsense banner appear to the right just next to the logo ?

I need to make sure that both div will never be superimposed (on all devices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

HTML:

```
<div id="logo">
Some code here for the logo
</div>

<div id="ad-banner"> 
    Ad banner goes here                 
</div>

<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
```

CSS:

```
#ad-banner 
{ 
    float: right; 
    margin-top: 60px; 
}
```

Putting the HTML in the `header-middle` div and the `#ad-banner` style into the `style.css` file. It should work.

Comment: Here is the direct link to the site : http://goo.gl/ESAnrA

I need to go sleep unfortunately but I will try your codes in few hours. Will get back to you !

Comment: Thank you for the update. It works !

However, can you tell for me why Iyou recommend to insert (<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>) at the end of the html. Is it necessary ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open WordPress Editor
2. Open the header.php file
3. In this file – look for the following code

```html
<header id=”masthead” role=”banner”>
```

4. Make the following change to the hgroup tag by adding style=”display:inline-block”
5. Immediately below the hgroup tag, add the Ad (Google AdSense) Code inside a span block as shown below:

```html
<span style=”float:right”>
<!– Paste Ad Sense Code below–>
</span>
```

6. Save the file

Source: http://techzog.com/wordpress/how-to-add-banner-ad-to-wordpress/